# SignalR after page refresh doesn't work properly

Tags: locking, signalr, angular5, signalr-hub, live-update

I am using SignalR in my angular5 website for presenting lock for documents. I am storing hub connection in data service and soon ad user logged in, I will start the connection. In each component which I need hub connection, I have an Observable and after the connection established, It listens to the hub. Everything is working properly. But after refreshing page, it will not show the result of SignalR command. If I click or mouse over on that page, then it will show the result of SignalR!

This is the code which run after login:

```
startConnection(): void {
//Create the hub connection for SignalR
this.dataService.connection = $.hubConnection(this.dataService.getServerConn());
this.dataService.authProxy = this.dataService.connection.createHubProxy('auth');
this.dataService.authProxy.on('handler', () => { });
this.dataService.authProxyCreated = false;
this.dataService.connection.qs = { "AuthenticationToken": sessionStorage.getItem('UMToken') };
if (this.dataService.connection.state != $.signalR.connectionState.connected)
  this.dataService.connection.start().done(() => {
    console.log('Connected to SignalR hub!');
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    console.log('Hub error -> ' + error);
  });
}
```

and this is the code in component which listen to the hub:

```
ngOnInit() {

//SignalR
if (this.storeDataService.connection.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected)
  this.registerSignalR();
this.storeDataService.connection.stateChanged((change) => {
  if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected)
    this.registerSignalR();
});
}
ngOnDestroy() {
this.storeDataService.authProxy.off('lockAuth');
this.storeDataService.authProxy.off('unlockAuth');
}

registerSignalR() {
this.storeDataService.authProxy.on('lockAuth', (authNo: string, username: string) => {
  var auth = this.queueList.data.find(p => p.AuthNo == authNo);
  if (auth) {
    auth.LockedOn = new Date();
    auth.LockedByUserName = username;
  }
});
this.storeDataService.authProxy.on('unlockAuth', (authNo: string) => {
  var auth = this.queueList.data.find(p => p.AuthNo == authNo);
  if (auth) {
    auth.RmiLockedOn = null;
  }
});
}
```

This is also the code in edit page which invoke lock:

```
if (this.dataService.connection.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
    this.dataService.authProxy.invoke('lock', this.authNo, this.userService.userName, this.userService.userId);
  }
  this.dataService.connection.stateChanged((change) => {
    if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
      this.dataService.authProxy.invoke('lock', this.authNo, this.userService.userName, this.userService.userId);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the code you used? Also, by refreshing the page, you mean pressing F5 in the browser? Did you try putting a breakpoint in your javascript code to check if the code reaches there at least?

Comment: I have added. Yes, I mean F5. And this problem only exists in chrome. @Alisson